# HashMap doesn't provide values in the order in which added them

Tags: java, android

I am putting values in HashMap.
But when I am reading values from that HashMap;
I am NOT getting those values in the ORDER in which I have added them.
Can any-one help me?.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`HashMap` doesn't guarantee that the insertion-order is preserved.

Use [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) if you need such guarantee.

> This implementation differs from HashMap in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally **the order in which keys were inserted** into the map (insertion-order).

Answer (score 4):

From the Java documentation:

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in
>   particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant
>   over time.

Answer (score 1):

HashMap doesn't guarantee the order in which items are returned. With LinkedHashMap you can retrieve items in the order they were added; with TreeMap, you can retrieve them sorted.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew, for giving alternate to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This is stated in the javadocs for `HashMap`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.